# Transform xml to cvs

Tags: java, xml, xslt, sax

i developed application for transform xml to cvs via xsl. I used DOM API,but it has bad performance ( in input i have 100000 xml size 200kb-20mb) i tried to use SAX API, but i receive wrong result output after transformation.
Dom api:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException {
    styleSheet = new File("1.xsl");
    builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    stylesource = new StreamSource(styleSheet);
    transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
}

public String transformXmlToCsv(String inputXml) {
    String csv = null;

    try {
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(inputXml));

        Document document = builder.parse(is);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
        csv = writer.toString();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception during transorming", e);
    }
    return csv;
}
```

}

SAX API:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance( );
    File xml = new File("019dc124-5057-43f3-aa5d-1d840536b1b5-1558467374000.xml");
    File styleSheet = new File("1.xsl");
    Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\proj\\xmlparser\\result.csv"));
    Source stylesource = new StreamSource(styleSheet);
    Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(stylesource);
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileReader(xml));   
    Source xmlSource = new SAXSource(is);
    trans.transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);       
}
```

Comment: You will need to explain exactly what goes wrong, i.e. which result you get for the first sample and how the second result is different, any exact error you get.

Comment: @MartinHonnen edited, no errors it is run succesfully

Comment: Show your XSL file.

Comment: @mentallurg aded short version of xsl

Comment: It is hard to tell from screenshots what is wrong but if unwanted indentation/whitespace is the problem then you can usually fix it using e.g. `<xsl:text>Case</xsl:text>` explicitly in your templates to output literal text.

Comment: At second sample it builds whole xml, but without tags, only text. I remove line 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> from xsl and have this output(second page) i think sax cannot evaluate xpath expressions

Comment: Well, show us minimal samples of XML and XSLT and wanted output and wrong output as code/text samples in your question and we can hopefully see what is wrong. The screenshots don't allow that. The only slight suspicion I have is that your XML has a default namespace declaration (e.g. `xmlns="http://example.com"`) on the root element and that the default, not namespace aware DocumentBuilder allows your XSLT code to ignore that while the SAX one puts the elements in a namespace, In that case you need to fix the XSLT to declare a prefix for the namespace and use it or switch to XSLT 2/3.

Comment: I switched xslt to version 2.0 it is not helped, at root element in xml i have namespace xmlns="com.swissre.magnum.client.v1".

Comment: Yes, namespace helped but i have to hardcode namecpase with any xpath expression?

Comment: To use XSLT 2 or 3, you can't simply set `version="2.0"` in the XSLT, you also need to put Saxon 9 HE on the class path (it is available on Maven or Sourceforge) and for your namespace problem you also need to add `xpath-default-namespace="com.swissre.magnum.client.v1"` as an attribute on the `xsl:stylesheet` root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might just have run into a variant of the most frequently asked question on using XSLT properly to select elements in a namespace, I think the default Java DocumentBuilder is not namespace aware so your XSLT code might see elements in a default namespace as being in no namespace so that your paths like `root/rootnode/name` work. On the other hand, using Sax I think the XSLT processor will see elements in the default namespace you say you have and then your paths don't work anymore as they select elements in no namespace.

To fix this, there are two ways: switch to XSLT 2/3 by putting Saxon 9 HE (latest version is 9.9) on the classpath and then use e.g. `xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/ns"` as an attribute on the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` root element.

Or, if you are stuck with XSLT 1, the only fix is to declare a prefix (e.g. `pf1`) for that namespace (e.g. `http://example.com/ns`) in the stylesheet e.g. `xmlns:pf1="http://example.com/ns"` and then change all XPath expresssions and match patterns to use the prefix so `root/rootnode/name` becomes `pf1:object/pf1:rootnode/pf1:name`.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your problem, then don't create a new `TransformerFactory`, `DocumentBuilderFactory` etc for every file that you're converting. Instantiating these JAXP factory classes is notoriously expensive because it involves searching the classpath. You haven't said what size the files are, but if you're parsing hundreds of thousands of very small XML files then the key to performance is to reuse the same parser; the DOM-vs-SAX difference is going to be negligible.

Comment: xml size is different( 200kb-20mb). I am already reuse parser(edited 1st message). Ok, how i can improve performance?

Comment: With performance, the devil is always in the detail. You need to start by telling us about the performance numbers you are achieving and how these fall short of your business requirements. Perhaps you're already doing as well as possible. Perhaps you need to rethink the whole process/workflow: if I were coming in as a consultant I would be asking why are you converting all this XML to CSV, what can you do with the CSV that you can't do with the XML? But that makes the question much too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: For transform 100000 xml it took 1h. Cvs I can send to Postgres dB and save to tables, with xml I can’t do this. At Monday I am trying to use sax api and see how much time it took. I have to process 100000 xml in 20 minutes.

Comment: I would generally reckon 1Gb per minute is a reasonable speed for processing XML; if you're processing 100K * 1Mb documents in 1 hour that's in line with that target (100Gb / hour). If you want to speed it up, cut out the intermediate CSV form: write a Java application that reads the XML and writes to the database directly using JDBC.

Comment: Note also that Saxon (-PE and higher) offers an extension that allows you to write directly to the database from XSLT code (see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!sql-extension ) I don't guarantee a speed-up relative to your current code but it's worth doing an experiment.

Comment: What do you mean:” java application that reads the xml” my xml extremely nested and that’s why I am using xslt with xpath it is easy to parse it. In csv I can store large amount of data and write to db, in java I can convert xml to objects, but I have not xsd, to create classes. And I can not use saxon pe in my project now.

Comment: My suggestion to use Java/JDBC was because I prefer not to to use SO as a sales platform; it appears I was right to think that you want a solution to this problem but don't want to pay £50 for software that solves it for you.

Comment: No you was’t right I can’t use this library because it is have to be approved and it take about half a year to wait approve.

Comment: You have my sympathies. I had one user buy the software and ask me to invoice it as a book because he didn't need approval for that.